# Nginx + passenger: Multiple domains need to point to different root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

Been working with Nginx and passenger.  I have successfully got one app / domain to work correctly.  But with my server I have 2+ domains I plan to server from nginx to their respective root directory where each rails app will live.

I have tried numerous techniques, but none work.  All domains take the first root setup, and not the root they should be.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
  server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name www.danielcw.info;
    root /root/public/danielcw.info/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    access_log  /root/public/danielcw.info/log/access.log;
    error_log /root/public/danielcw.info/log/error.log;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
  } 

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.ericoppi.com;
    root /root/public/ericcoppi.com/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    access_log  /root/public/ericcoppi.com/log/access.log;
    error_log /root/public/ericcoppi.com/log/error.log;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server after making the configuration changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That configuration should work correctly - the only change I would make is to serve both www and no-www via nginx:

```
  server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name danielcw.info www.danielcw.info;
    root /root/public/danielcw.info/public;
    access_log  /root/public/danielcw.info/log/access.log;
    error_log /root/public/danielcw.info/log/error.log;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
  } 

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ericoppi.com www.ericoppi.com;
    root /root/public/ericcoppi.com/public;
    access_log  /root/public/ericcoppi.com/log/access.log;
    error_log /root/public/ericcoppi.com/log/error.log;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
  }
```

Make sure you have restarted nginx after editing the config file.

Comment: Thank you, I guess adding in that last little bit got it to work.

Comment: If you visited the no-www version with your previous config, it would match neither of the server blocks.  nginx would then select the server it considered as the "default", thus making it appear like you were seeing the same site on both domains.